# php to read from 11st line to 20th line of CSV file

Tags: php, csv

This is read from 11st line to end line.I am a biginner in php ,I don't know how to read from 11st line to 20th line ?

```
//Open data.csv
$file = fopen("test.csv", "r");
//Read data until end
$rowcount = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
$rowcount++;
    $row = fgetcsv($file);
    if ($rowcount <= 10)
continue;
    $fp=fopen("note.txt","a");
fputs($fp,$row[0]."\r\n");
}
//Close file
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it. The solution could be more elegant, but I have focused on simplicity and understandability. I have been inspired by the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) manual.

```
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while ((($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) && ($row < 20)) {
        $row++;
        if ($row <= 10) {
            continue;
        }
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do:

```
$file = file("test.csv");
for($i=10;$i<20;$i++){
    file_put_contents("note.txt",$file[$i]."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
}
```